# NOAUTH HELLO must be called with the client already authenticated

Tags: java, spring-boot, lettuce, redis-sentinel

We cannot connect to the master via sentinel.

Error:
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: NOAUTH HELLO must be called with the client already authenticated, otherwise the HELLO AUTH   option can be used to authenticate the client and select the RESP protocol version at the same time.

im use spring-boot-starter-data-redis:2.6.6

```
@Bean
public RedisURI redisUri() {
    return RedisURI.create("redis-sentinel://pass@host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3/1?sentinelMasterId=mymaster");
}

@Bean
public RedisClient redisClient(RedisURI redisUri) {
    return RedisClient.create(redisUri);
}

@Bean
public StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> statefulRedisConnection(RedisClient redisClient) {
    return redisClient.connect();
}

@Bean
public RedisCommands<String, String> redisCommands(StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> statefulRedisConnection) {
    return statefulRedisConnection.sync();
}
```

Where can i set the password?

Comment: How did you fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Redis version > 6 you should define your username and password in case you use sentinel.

For instance:

```
spring:
  redis:
    port: 6379
    username: default
    password: your-pw
    sentinel:
      username: ${spring.redis.username}
      password: ${spring.redis.password}
      master: redis
      nodes:
        - your-redis-node:26379
```

Or add `.data` case you use spring data